# How to change an instance variable of all instances of a class at once, Python

Tags: python, class, static, instance, non-static

I want to do an operation on all the instances of a class, using the non-static variables specific to each class instance. I want to do this operation in one go without treating each class instance individually.

An example of what I want to do:

```
# Define the example class
class Example:
    __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

# Initalise class instances
a = Example(1,2)
b = Example(7,3)

# Operate on the class objects simultaneously:
All_Example_class_instances.x = All_Example_class_instances.x + All_Example_class_instances.y + 5
```

At the moment I am looping through all the class objects individually:

```
Example_instance_list = [a, b]

for instance in Example_instance_list:
    instance.x = instance.x + instance.y + 5
```

But, I am trying to avoid having to loop through each class instance.

Is there are way to do the same operation on all the instances of the Example() class in one go (without loops) using non-static variables that are specific to each class instance?

Comment: is there a reason the variable has to be tied to the instance? If not, you can store it in a class variable instead. Instead of calling instance.x, you would modify Example.x

Comment: I agree with @jrmylow , if you want to have a same value for all the instances, you can make it as a class variable.

Comment: The variable is unique to each instance and the way that the variable is modified depends on other instance variables, but the calculation that I want to do on each class instance is the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, at least not directly in the way you're talking about it. Each instance has an independent set of instance variables, so there's no central place where you can set or change a value such that all of the existing instances will reflect the change.

However, you might be interested in properties, which is a way you can write the same code you would use to access a variable but have it call a function instead. Just for example, if you wanted to make a class that appears to have two variables, `a` and `b`, such that `b` is always one more than `a`:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.a + 1
```

With this, you can do the following:

```
>>> instance = Example(1)
>>> instance.a, instance.b
(1, 2)
>>> instance.a = 5
>>> instance.a, instance.b
(5, 6)
```

It's also possible to allow setting a property by writing code like

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.a + 1
    @b.setter
    def set_b(self, value):
        self.a = value - 1
```

Other things along these lines are possible as well; you can find a lot of information about this elsewhere online.

In your case, you may want to define either your `x` or your `y` or both as properties which check a central location (maybe a class variable or module-level variable) for some value and compute the property value based on that centrally stored value. Perhaps you might want setter methods that would manipulate that centrally stored value as well.

Answer (score -1):

You could make an instance variable that changes depending on a static class variable, through a method or directly. Changing the static, you could modificate the instance on a desired way, maybe in a diferent way for each object (depending on more variables or methods.....)